# COPY from s3 to Redshift in docker container timeout

Tags: docker, amazon-redshift

I am trying to perform a COPY of large chunk of data from s3 to Redshift. It works normally from my mac via psql, but when I try to run it from a docker container running locally (using docker-airflow), I always get this error:

> SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected The connection to the server was lost.
>   Attempting reset: Succeeded.

Here is example on how I run it locally:

```
# First, I connect using psql
psql -h <connection_string> -u meh -d database -p 5439
# Then I issue this command.
COPY test.test from 's3://data/manifest_uuid' with credentials '' 
FORMAT AS JSON 'auto' TRUNCATECOLUMNS COMPUPDATE ACCEPTINVCHARS manifest MAXERROR 100;
```

Within airflow container, same query is executed using psycopg2:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=database, host=endpoint, port=port, user=user, password=password, sslmode='require')
with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute(q, args)
    if fetch_one:
        result = cur.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            return None
        return result
    elif fetch_all:
        return cur.fetchall()
    else:
       conn.commit()
```

Here is how I try to run it from container:

```
# I try to connect to the container
docker exec -it `docker ps|grep worker|awk 'END {print $1}'` /bin/bash
```

And then I run exactly the same as I do locally.

I can connect to the container, run psql from there and do all sorts of queries, and even the COPY command works, if the file is small enough. 
I tried following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html#change-tcpip-settings, and I verified that the options suggested are set to the values suggested, but I still get this issue.

UPDATE: Here is a gist with a dockerfile. To reproduce you also need a redshift cluster and some 1-2gb file with json that can be moved to Redshift with COPY command. If you create a container from that image, connect to it and try to run copy command, you would most likely see the same issue.

https://gist.github.com/drapadubok/da04548dace5d4ff4198631841322402

Comment: How are you issuing the COPY command, through psql?

Comment: It might be useful to share more details about how the copy command looks and how you're executing it.

Comment: Thank you! Added the details, please tell if more clarifications can be added

Comment: Are you using Docker for Mac? It may be related to this issue: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2442 You could try the experimental patched build linked in the comments there.

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino this helped! I updated the docker to the latest version as suggested in github issue (17.12.0-ce-mac49) and it worked! Thank you! Can you submit this as an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: @DmitrySmirnov I am glad it worked. I moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a [recent regression bug](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2442) in Docker for Mac, which makes TCP connections time out.

Updating Docker to *v17.12.0-ce-mac49* fixes the problem, as confirmed by the OP.